# how to define settings for a class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, app-config

I have `Test project library` & need to define number of values as configuration. So I went ahead & added the app.config file to class library.

```
<add key="url" value="http://www.google.com">
```

In one of the class of library project, Browser.cs

I am trying to read the value by adding the reference to System.Configuration.

```
public void GetUrl()
{
   var obj = new Page();
   obj.Url = ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["Url"].toString();
   //it is returning null 
}
```

& there is no exe or web project, it is suite of Test Project & class libraries.

How do I meet such requirement in the right way??

Comment: How are you planning on reading settings from something that doesn't run? Libraries do not execute. Executables do.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Just Running all tests from Visual Studio menu

Comment: So your question is really, "how do i read configuration from app.config into a project using visual Studio's built in unit test framework?"

Comment: @ChristopherPisz, not unit test project but Automation functional test cases (Selenium)

Comment: isn't `NameValueCollection` case-sensitive? I.e if `key="url"`, shouldn't you get `Appsettings["url"]`?